# Why my jquery script doesn't work in my webform which was inherited from MasterPage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, master-pages

I have a master page and in its head, i have :

```
<script src="Script/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="Stylesheet/Master.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

and i have a webform (by name=Login.aspx) which was inherited from my master page, in Login.aspx i have :

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

     <input id="t1" type="password" placeholder="Passwords" class="login-input-class1" runat="server"  ClientID="Static" />
     <input id="t2" type="text" placeholder="ConfirmPasswords" class="login-input-class1" runat="server"  ClientID="Static"/>
     <label class="display" id="lblerror">Error</label>

 <script>

      $(document).ready(function () {

          $("#t2").change(function () {
              if ($("#t1").val() === $("#t2").val()) {
                  $("#lblerror").addClass("display");
              }

              else {
                  $("#lblerror").removeClass("display");
              }
          });
      });

</script>                    

</asp:Content>
```

and in Master.css i have :

```
.display {
 display:none;
```

}

But my script does not work, what is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the ID changes at run-time. You should use `ClientId` for your controls.

You can also use `ClientIDMode="Static"` to stop the id form changing to it's original.
More Detail about [client id mode](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/34151/ASP-NET-4-0-Client-ID-Feature)

```
$("#<%= Control.ClientID %>").addClass("display");

  $("#<%=t2.ClientID %>").change(function () {
                if ($("#<%=t1.ClientID %>").val() === $("#<%=t2.ClientID %>").val()) {
                   $("#lblerror%>").addClass("display");
                }
               else {
                   $("#lblerror").removeClass("display");
                }
            });
```

### Edit 1

```
<input id="t1" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="login-input-class1"
        runat="server" />
<input id="t2" type="text" placeholder="ConfirmPassword" class="login-input-class1"
        runat="server" />
```

And jQuery

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#<%=t2.ClientID %>").change(function () {
            if ($("#<%=t1.ClientID %>").val() === $("#<%=t2.ClientID %>").val()) {
                $("#lblerror%>").addClass("display");
            }
            else {
                $("#lblerror").removeClass("display");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: It is an input and it is not an asp.net button.. is there any differences?

Comment: Does not matter if you have **runat="server"**. You can also use class selector rather than ID selector if you have different classes over your controls.

Comment: I do it but it give me an error: The name 'lblerror' does not exist in the current context

Comment: ok that was a mistake ignore the client id in that line I am updating my answer.

Comment: i edit like this :                                            <input ClientId ="t1" type="password" placeholder="Password" class="login-input-class1" runat="server"   />
                                                               <input ClientId ="t2" type="text" placeholder="ConfirmPassword" class="login-input-class1" runat="server"  />    But it give me error: The name 't2' does not exist in the current context

Answer (score 0):

Seem like you want:

```
if ($("#t2").val() === $("#t1").val()) {
```

or:

```
if ($(this).val() === $("#t1").val()) {
```

instead of:

```
if ($("#t1").val() === $("#t1").val()) {
```